# How to bring up a network interface only if it is physically present in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, boot, wireless, networking, 14.04

This is a follow-up on [my old question](https://askubuntu.com/q/319631/174873):

> What would be the best way to make kernel bring a network interface up
>   only if it is physically plugged in? So, if it doesn't exist, just
>   move on with initializing other interfaces (if any) and continue to
>   the login screen, without "waiting for network configuration" delay.

The solution then came up with then was the following in `etc/network/interfaces`, it used to work in 12.04:

```
auto wlan9
iface wlan9 inet manual
        wpa-ssid MYSSD
        wpa-psk MYKEY
        wpa-proto RSN
        wpa-pairwise CCMP
        wpa-group CCMP
        wireless-power off
        pre-up if [ -f /sys/class/net/wlan9/operstate ]; then ifconfig wlan9 up; fi
        up if [ -f /sys/class/net/wlan9/operstate ]; then dhclient wlan9; fi
```

**Unfortunately, it stopped working once I upgraded to 14.04 Trusty Tahr.** If the interface is physically absent (i.e. the USB WiFi card unplugged), I again experience the 2 minutes "waiting for network configuration" delay.

How can I get the same logic working in 14.04?

Comment: Can you try using tools designed for this job, like Wicd? Wicd has a curses-based interface, iirc, and Network Manager 0.9.8.10 (coming soon) will bring a similar one soon.

Comment: @muru, this is a lean-and-mean headless system without GUI and without Network Manager. I prefer something scriptable, that works with `etc/network/interfaces`. I'm not familiar with Wicd, can it do that?

Comment: Check https://packages.debian.org/jessie/network-manager or http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/network-manager and you'll see that NM does not drag in GUI dependencies - I'm pretty sure you'll already have most dependencies already installed. Wicd does not touch `/etc/network/interfaces`, because it, like NM and netctl are higher level utilities. People who entertain the misconception of NM's bloatedness tend to like wicd.

Comment: @mure, thanks, I'll look at wcid and one more time at NM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an upstart job for this. Rip out the pre-up and up sections then make a file /etc/init/network-interface_wlan9.conf :

```
start on net-device-added INTERFACE=wlan9
task
exec ifup wlan9
```

Comment: A good bit of info, I'll keep it as an option. Meanwhile, [here's what helped](http://askubuntu.com/a/489572/174873) so far.

Comment: That should work with the systemd transition, so I would recommend it. I just assumed from your older question that allow-hotplug did not work.

Comment: Indeed, allow-hotplug didn't work that way for me in 12.04, but it works for 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `allow-hotplug` instead of `auto` seems to have helped.

```
allow-hotplug wlan9
iface wlan9 inet manual
...
```

This did not work for me in v12.04, the boot delay was still there. Apparently, I was not the only one: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905244