# What happens to upstart scripts in a migration from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.01?

Tags: networking, upstart

I am in the early stages of planning a migration from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1, and the first thing I'm reading is that upstart is gone in favor of systemv. I have some custom network upstart scripts that I had to write to overcome a problem with the old failsafe upstart script in 14.04; now that upstart is gone, what happens to the other scripts I wrote? Are they just discarded?

(The scripts were to bring up some bridges and taps in my unusual network configuration that was causing failsafe to hang while waiting for a network interface to come up -- details of that problem and my solution are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597729/how-should-i-configure-ubuntu-upstart-for-unusual-network-configuration). At this point, I don't even know if I need the hacked up interface file I ended up writing *because* of failsafe...grrrr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're ignored. The files remain there, but nothing uses them. If they're `init.d` scripts, on the other hand, [`systemd-sysv-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysv-generator.html) will try to parse them and start them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks muru! If I could trouble you to review my prior issue (linked in the original question), I had to do quite a bit of surgery to my initial interfaces file *because* of upstart. I'm not even sure those changes are necessary now, but I obviously have no way of testing it without doing the upgrade. Will I need to "unhack" interfaces because the scripts I wrote will no longer be fired?

Comment: @DavidW yes, if you use Upstart scripts to bring up interfaces now, you'll have to go back to `interfaces`, or write systemd units. I suspect the changes won't be needed now, one of the reason behind systemd's  adoption is that it uses a different way of starting units, where Upstart never did really handle complex start-on/stop-on settings well. (Of course, systemd has its own warts, but not *this* particular one.)

Comment: Good enough. Now all I have to do is remember how I wrote the interfaces file originally  when I built this box about two years ago LOL :)  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Actually, as I've researched this further, I've found I can still go back to upstart on 16.04.1. For my purposes, this may be the simpler path and should keep my downtime much lower for the migration/upgrade. I should be able to "do-upgrade", reboot, log in, reinstall upstart, reboot, and be done with it.

Comment: @DavidW yes, there is a boot-to-upstart option. You don't need to reinstall upstart, it's still installed by default on 16.04 (but it's not the default init.) But I'm not sure how well that will play with other services.

Comment: Thanks for that info, @muru! I had not considered the possibility of adverse impacts arising from an upstart boot under 16.04 relating to other services that may assume systemd is now the default init. *siigh* too much to think about LOL :)