# UNCLAIMED network (network/ethernet controller). How to claim?

Tags: networking, 22.04, ethernet

I am on Ubuntu 22.04

`$ sudo 1shw -class network`

```sh
*-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Network controller 
product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz 
vendor: Intel Corporation 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0 
version: 1a 
width: 64 bits
Clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list 
configuration: latency=0 
resources: memory:fc400000-fc403fff

*-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Ethernet controller 
product: Ethernet Controller 1225-V 
vendor: Intel Corporation 
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
version: 03 width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap list 
configuration: latency-0
resources: memory: fc200000-fc2fffff memory: fc300000-fc303fff
```

`$ lspci -knn I grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```sh
06:00.0 Network controller (0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller (0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (8086:153] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Controller I225-V (1043:87d2)
```

How do I associate the `Network controller` and `Ethernet controller`?

**EDIT**

```sh
$ sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

Output:

```sh
dpkg-query: package 'Linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-58-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg - -info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

Comment: I think this might be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/319631/how-to-bring-up-a-network-interface-only-if-it-is-physically-present

Comment: I don't think that will help me

Comment: @Wingarmac Correct. Any answer that is ten years old related to wireless is now obsolete.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem!

Here is what I did:

1. spam the shift key on startup to get into the grub menu
2. go to advanced options
3. click on recovery mode for a different linux kernel that is not having issues
4. click enable networking
5. click fix broken packages
6. click resume boot

Bam! Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Some kernel packages are not installed.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

This meta package should install all kernel modules.

Comment: I cannot run this because I can't connect to the internet at all.